# While Loop vs Modulus operator

Tags: c#, .net-core, while-loop

I have two programs performing the same task i.e. calculate the Least Common Multiple (LCM) of two numbers.The first program which contains a while loop out performs the second program.

Program 1:

```cs
 temp1 = firstNumber;
        temp2 = secondNumber;

        while (firstNumber != secondNumber)
        {
            if (firstNumber > secondNumber)
            {
                firstNumber -= secondNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                secondNumber -= firstNumber;
            }
        }   

        lcm = (temp1 * temp2) / firstNumber;
```

[image]

Program 2:

```cs
int f =1;
    
        //int f = firstNumber > secondNumber? (firstNumber%secondNumber == 0 ? secondNumber : 1) : (secondNumber%firstNumber == 0 ? firstNumber : 1);
        if(firstNumber > secondNumber)
        {
            if( firstNumber%secondNumber == 0)
                f = secondNumber;               
        }
        else{
            if(secondNumber%firstNumber ==0)
                f = firstNumber;
        }
        
        lcm = (firstNumber*secondNumber)/f;
```

[image]

The input to both programs was : 1513,3

#### I assumed as the difference between the two numbers increased the first program would take longer, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

What is the reason behind the first program performing better than the second one?
Ps. I am not the author of the first program.

Comment: How are you measuring this?

Comment: You ran the programs one time each with a single input? The program took WAY longer to load into memory and get started than it did to do some extremely simple arithmetic one time is my guess.

Comment: First of all, your second approach is wrong. For instance, for inputs 6 and 10 it gives 60 instead of 30 ... Furthermore, how often did your run these tests? Once? Then your measurements are not enough to draw any conclusions.

Comment: Furthermore, how was the measurement even done? What Timer did you use for measurements? Does it even have a high enough resolution for the measurement of such short running processes?

Comment: I just added one result but ran the tests multiple times and with inputs

Comment: How did you run your tests "multiple" time. Just started the executable multiple times? Then your startup process will take way longer than the actual calculation. What is your test environment? Because it seems rather strange that such an easy calculation would take nearly 0.1 seconds on a remotely decent machine ...

Comment: You initialize `int f = 1` and you only change `f` if either `firstNumber%secondNumber == 0` or `secondNumber%firstNumber ==0` which isn't the case for inputs 10 and 6. So your result will always be `firstNumber*secondNumber` unless one of those is a multiple of the other ... But the correct formula is `first * second / GCD(first, second)` with GCD being the greatest common divisor (ie what you are calculating with the loop in the first approach)

Comment: Your "measurement" output seem very much to be from running a script at dotnetfiddle.net. But that measurement also includes starting the runtime, loading the compiled script ... Furthermore, you have no control over the hardware where the script is run. It might be, that every measurement is run on a completely different machine. That's not how you do performance measurements. You have to setup a controlled environment and eliminate all sideeffects ...

Answer (score 1):

Your sample size isn't large enough to draw performance conclusions.  Any number of things could have been going on during the execution of the code.

As C# relies on the runtime, it performs many operations that can impact performance (most notably the Garbage Collector).  Even running the same program multiple times can vary.

This is also why you never trust a .Net timer to be accurate, there are many timer options, none of them will count time accurately.  The most accurate way to determine a time something runs is to create two time stamps at the start and stop point and subtract them.

In order to get an accurate benchmark, you need to average the running time across many runs.

One other thing I would like to share is that micro-optimizing such trivial code for performance is rarely necessary.  Write what makes it easier to read, don't try to squeeze every millisecond out of it.  Large looping tasks can be optimized as identified, but basic calculations such as this aren't going to make a bit of difference in the end.